# $G$ contain an abel normal subgroup $H$ and $G/H$ is solvable of degree $n-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ is a solvable finite group of degree $n$ then $G$ contain an abelian normal subgroup $H$ and $G/H$ is solvable of degree $n-1$.

I guess $H=Z(G)$ then $G/Z(G)$ is solvable group with degree $\leq n$ but i can't prove $G/Z(G)$ has solvable degree $n-1$

Comment: Why do you write non-empty? All groups are non-empty. What do you mean by the degree of a solvable group? It is possible that $Z(G)=1$ so you cannot use your argument.

Comment: sorry, i mean $|G|>1$

Comment: But you still need to define the degree.I searched for "degree of solvable group" and did not find anything useful.

Comment: It means the length of $G_0=[G,G]$, $G^{(i+1)}=[G^{(i)},G^{(i)}]$ is $n$ with $G^{(n)}=e$

Comment: OK, so then you can choose the abelian normal subgroup to be $G^{(n-1)}$, where $n$ is minimal such that $G^{(n)}=1$. Also, there is no need to assume that $G$ is finite.